# How to improve my programming language?

Tags: testing

Hello everybody I have been making a programming language for some time now as a good learning experience etc and improving my programming skills.

It can use a lot of improvements and I'm sure somebody might be willing to find things that I can improve or help make it better.

My programming language has syntax, arrays etc very similar to PHP but with macro features like AutoIt and RegEx syntax of Perl etc. It is a bit of a mix and match of many features I liked most about other languages.

It includes a vast number of functions as shown here
[Function Reference](http://ubersoft.org/sputnik/wiki/index.php?title=Function_Reference)

With a pretty largely documented language features and syntax here
[Language Reference](http://ubersoft.org/sputnik/wiki/index.php?title=Language_Reference)

I'm looking to improve my language in every way possible which includes but not limited to finding bugs, creating test cases (to test all features and report success) etc.

I'm looking for people willing to help out or test or try make things and see how well it goes or perhaps find it useful and enjoy it.

If you can or know somebody who will be willing to help improve my language let me know.

Project Goals:

- Get everything tested and make sure it all works (I can estimate at least 90+% works correctly)
- Create a test script for every function where all tests get run from a single script (partially started)
- Create a new GUI system (the current one works fine and can produce good applications but needs a remake)
- Add another 1000 functions (Specifically all the stuff that's lacking such as Date/XML etc)
- Create a series of games in Sputnik (So far I have completed one game which is a full Pengo remake of the original Amiga game it looks/works/runs exactly same as original)
- Create a proper IDE (Even if that means using Eclipse or something) for Sputnik the current IDE is made in Sputnik and although its not bad it is lacking a ton of stuff that more advanced IDE's have
- Complete the XNA library for Sputnik or drop it in favor of SDL/OpenGL
- Support all .NET types natively (Currently this is only partial but yet surprisingly good seeing DotNet on wiki will show what's done so far on that)
- Need a Linux+Mac DLL creating to provide all additional features to Sputnik specific for them platforms (Sputnik runs on Mono) currently only Windows gets a beefy dll and provides around 200 extra functions to Sputnik.
- Finalize the grammar so it never changes to do this it will need to be perfect
- Fix the wiki so all functions have correct argument names (instead of expression, expression2) and also fix all Return 1,0 to true/false (Boolean was added later to Sputnik after hundreds of functions were documented...)
- Need to make a very extensive Win32 include scripts for Sputnik (Sputnik supports calling DLL files and creating C++ style structures for use in such DLL calls) so it can use all windows APIs directly
- I want something similar to LPEG for Sputnik of course Sputniks build in parser is very powerful but it does require an IDE to generate it's grammar sheets where as something like LPEG could be done in user code
- I want to complete LINQ in Sputnik so far only Where() is complete and that is just a prototype it wants a complete LINQ implementation (I like LINQ)

Design philosophy

- Sputnik supports the Perl idea of "There is an insane number of ways to do one thing" (as demonstrated by having an Unless to go with the If and so on) that said Sputnik code can be very clear and easy to understand and very simplified.
- I believe in strongly shortened code and will always seek to use the lowest amount of code possible to get the job done (As long as it's the fastest)
- Sputnik includes the "my" keyword to make a value be local scope only same a Perl this helps with a good design

Comment: Consider Code Review if you want someone to review the implementation, or perhaps Programmers for feedback on the ideas. However, your question is definitely not appropriate for this site, sorry.

Comment: Just because I'm curious: what language did you use to implement your compiler/interpreter (assuming one exists)?

Comment: Everything was made in C# it parses the entire source code builds everything it needs then begins executing the code similar to PHP/Perl.

Comment: uneonneo -- Suggest a site thanks.

Comment: @UberFoX: My guess is that they were recommending the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Code Review -- I do want to get it to point where its grammar etc is final with all code verified and working properly (test cases to prove it so far this is only partially done with modest test cases)

Comment: Well I basically got booted off Code Review Stack Exchange but that's ok I never expected anybody to be interested.

Comment: @UberFoX: Well, why did you get booted? Are you sure it's a lack of interest?

Comment: @UberFoX - I never realized you got recommended to go over to code review. but, as a new user, to both SO, and Code Review, I really expect you to read the welcome page, and to read what's on topic. When you posted to code review, you posted no code. The first thing it says questions have to have to be on-topic is: *Is code included directly in my question? (See Make sure you include your code in your question below.)* You did not get booted off code review, you removed the question yourself. And, we are not hostile there. We just have a process.

Comment: @rolfl: This is why I asked the question above. I suspect the OP's assessment isn't entirely fair.

Comment: I posted links to code and there is downloads to code I couldnt post code in the topic even if I tried to since there is a 30,000 limit I even attempted to paste a module into a new topic 3 minutes ago only to see the 30,000 limit.

Comment: I'm not sure what people are supposed to get from such snippets of code when I'm talking about a language not a few lines of code...

Comment: Let's take this conversation to the [Code Review chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) but you may want to read this [Code Review meta question first](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/can-i-put-my-code-on-a-third-party-site-and-link-to-the-site-in-my-question)

Comment: @UberFoX: 30,000 _what_ limit? Characters? You're worried about hitting a 30,000 question character limit? I suspect there is a better way to accomplish what you're going at here. Maybe you should take rolfl's advice and move this to their chat room.

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: David I have single source files here numbering up 10k+ lines with 300,000 chars etc asking me to post it in the topic is just... not possible. (tons of them)

Comment: @UberFoX: Oh, right. What a pain-in-the-ass. Do you have a repo set up for your language? It might help the CR guys to link them to some code (rather than flood your question with it), and maybe point them to specific sections that you want to discuss. This might be more useful than asking questions like "how can I improve my language?".

Answer (score 0):

```
Operator lgi
Test if first value is lower or higher than the second (both treated as strings, case insensitive).
```

Who asked for that feature?

Comment: I guess it just added for the hell of it

Comment: @UberFoX: I guess it would be nice to preface this sort of post with your goals or design philosophies, if they exist beyond "this is a learning exercise". Depending, "for the hell of it" may or may not be a good reason to add a feature to your language.

Comment: David Frye -- Well I didn't want to bloat the post with all that since I thought it would piss people off.

Comment: LGI was added because it fits with all the other string comparison functions.

Comment: @UberFoX: I don't know that that sort of stuff would necessarily be post bloat, but either way, you did manage to include a _lot_ of information about your language without bloating your post. Maybe write up a page about that sort of stuff (or don't, your choice really) so that you may link to it.